# Reverse find('threaded') in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to mimic a reddit feature. When you link to a specific comment in a threaded list ([example](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/ak0ff/dear_reddit_why_is_the_concept_of_a_god/c0hz4th)), you can add a var 'context' in the url to show the context.
I can show you the comment I want you to see, plus a parent ([context=1](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/ak0ff/dear_reddit_why_is_the_concept_of_a_god/c0hz4th?context=1)) or the parent's parent ([context=2](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/ak0ff/dear_reddit_why_is_the_concept_of_a_god/c0hz4th?context=2)) and so on.

Now, cakePHP simplifies the threaded thing with [find('threaded');](http://book.cakephp.org/view/812/find-threaded), and I can link a comment and show a thread downside, but how can I make it upside, finding recursively parents `n` times?

Thanks, have an excelent 2010!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TreeBehavior::getpath()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/235/getpath) for the comment you have the `id` for (does 2 queries).

Pop `context` items off the path array.

Comment: Right! Thanks! I was not using the Tree behaviour, I was just assigning a parent_id field.

Comment: Cool, `TreeBehavior` is there to be used, but if you don't want to use MPTT, you can do it with recursive queries: Find the comment you have the `id` for. Find it's parent (`parent_id`), repeat `context` times. This will result in `context`+1 queries, instead of 2.